# I want to make python identify if `num1` and `num2` were numbers or not in this calculator so that python can notify you're not typing in valid things

Tags: python

I want to make python identify if `num1` and `num2` were numbers or not in this calculator so that python can notify you're not typing in valid things. Maybe using if statements?

```
num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
op = input("What operator would you use?")
if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print("Invalid operator")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it in a `try`-`except` block:

```
try:
    num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid number")
```

If you wanted to keep prompting the user:

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        break
    except:
        print("Invalid number")
```

And do the same for `num2`.